# Object Expected error implementing jquery suckerFish menu

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am attempting to implement the suckerfish menu found on this [tutorial.](http://be.twixt.us/jquery/suckerFish.php)  I get "object expected" error from the sample javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#nav-one li").hover(
            function () { $("ul", this).fadeIn("fast"); },
            function () { }
        );
        if (document.all) {
            $("#nav-one li").hoverClass("sfHover");
        }
    });
```

I have imported the JQuery using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

The JQuery import is in the page header.  The javascript is just inside the `<body>`.
It would be nice if I could tell which object is having the issue instead of being pointed at this block of code.  I'm new to JQuery and beginner level javascript.

**UPDATE**
The start of the menu:

```
<ul id="nav-one" class="nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#item1">item 1</a>
                <ul>
```

(I think the #nav-one points to the id of the menu "nav-one").

And I believe this css covers the "sfHover" part:

```
#nav-one li.sfHover a {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'object expected' error can occur when you are not including jQuery correctly.  Do you have that 'jquery-1.4.1.js' file in the directory the `src` attribute is pointing to?

To test if this is the problem, try replacing your jQuery include with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That will request jQuery from Google's servers.

Edit:

If I use your example code and the jQuery include I mentioned above, I don't get that error.  But you'll also need to include the

```
$.fn.hoverClass = function(c) {
return this.each(function(){
    $(this).hover( 
        function() { $(this).addClass(c);  },
        function() { $(this).removeClass(c); }
    );
});
};
```

part from your example.  That defines `hoverClass` as a jQuery method (it is not part of that standard jQuery library).

Comment: That got rid of the object expected error. The menu works, but not like the tutorial. The tutorial has a nice fade effect that is not functioning. I get no errors and I still have the code implemented that you see above. Since there's no errors at this point I'm ever more at a loss then I was before. Also, using "../Scripts/jquery.js" worked instead of "~/Scripts/jquery.js" even though the webform.aspx and Scripts folder are in the same parent directory.  Note that the extra code you included is in my code as well.

Comment: I downloaded the jquery.js file from the tutorial and the fade started working.  I thought this file was just the import of jquery, but apparently it is not.  It's just one function with a whole bunch of jibberish, but it works so yea...

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - Yes, mine must have worked the same way as your (no nice fade) until I included all the styles included on the example page.  It looks like the css handles the show/hide of the menu items (and the styling of course), so you'll need that on your page.